# How to get Poketch?

Tags: pokemon-diamond-pearl-remakes

How to get Poketch?

It is required to progress eastward toward *Oreburg City*.

I found three clowns? Are there more clowns?
Noone in Poketch company wants to give me prize and now I run around and re-talk to every NPC because no one told me where to receive prize.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are only **three** Clowns to snatch Coupons from, road-block NPC dialog just makes you think there are more to be found. Talk to each to receive Coupon.

[image]

Afterwards NPC will spawn at central road, between fountain and Pokemon Center.
[image: receive Poketch]

Clowns are located near Pokemart (east of fountain), TV Station (north of fountain), and Poketch Company (near western exit).

To open Poketch, click **R** (upper right shoulder button), Clicking **R** again will switch between small and full views. Hold **R** to hide it. Button on right side of Poketch switches apps, Poketch can be controlled with virtual cursor (L-Stick) or touchscreen.

[image: Poketch]